# Bootstrap Div inside dd, alignment issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align **div** tag inside **dd** tag. but the **div** is getting on the new line. 
I have to use **div** for using it as javascript selector.

HTML

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal dl-horizontal-info">
    <dt>created</dt>
    <dd>2013-11-24 09:47:55 GMT</dd>

    <dt>uploaders</dt>
    <dd><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i> <div id="uploaders">445453</div></dd>

    <dt>downloaders</dt>
    <dd><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i> <div id="downloaders">123123</div> <a href="javascript" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right" id="refreshbtn"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Refresh</a></dd>

    <dt>Updated</dt>
    <dd id="date">2013-11-24 09:47:55 GMT</dd>
</dl>
```

CSS

```
@import url("http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.0.3/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css");
@import url("http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css");
@import url("http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css");


.dl-horizontal-info > dt{float:left;width:120px;overflow:hidden;clear:left;text-align:left;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap}
.dl-horizontal-info > dd{margin-left:130px}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/whats_wrong/y22ZH/

In above example the **Div** tag having **id** uploaders
and **Div** tag having **id** downloaders are getting on the new line. how can i get then on the same line as of **dd** and icons.

Comment: What elements are you speaking of?

Comment: just edited question, please check it again.

Comment: `"I have to use div for using it as javascript selector."` You DO NOT need to use divs. You can use `<span id="uploaders">` and then you won't need to add any CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display **uploaders** and **downloaders** values in same line you can use **span** tags instead of **div** tags.
for example:

```
 <dl class="dl-horizontal dl-horizontal-info">
    <dt>created</dt>
    <dd>2013-11-24 09:47:55 GMT</dd>
    <dt>uploaders</dt>
    <dd><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i> <span id="uploaders">445453</span></dd>
    <dt>downloaders</dt>
    <dd><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i> <span id="downloaders">123123</span> <a href="javascript" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right" id="refreshbtn"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Refresh</a></dd>
    <dt>Updated</dt>
    <dd id="date">2013-11-24 09:47:55 GMT</dd>
</dl>
```

Check this link: [Updated code](http://jsfiddle.net/sQp2D/)

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS for #uploaders and #downloaders (or simply dd > div):

```
display: inline;
```

Answer (score 1):

try it..

```
dd div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to add `style: "display: inline"` to the divs, or `div { display: inline }` to get them to appear on the same line